# add_filter('wp_title') doesn't replace my title tag (WordPress plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, title

I am trying to change the title of my detail page to the name of the car.
I have made a plugin that fills the detail page with the car information. But now I can't get the add_filter('wp_title') to work in my plugin.

Here is the code I tried:

```
function init() {
    hooks();
}
add_action('wp', 'init');

function hooks() {
    if(get_query_var('car_id') != "") {
        add_filter('wp_title', 'addTitle', 100);
        add_action('wp_head', 'fillHead');
    }
    add_shortcode('showCar', 'showCar');
}

function addTitle() {
    $api_url_klant = API_URL . '/gettitle/' . get_option("ac") . '/' . get_query_var('car_id');
    $title = getJSON($api_url_klant);
    return $title['merk'] . " " . $title['model'] . " - " . $title['bedrijf'];
}
```

The addTitle() function works just fine. It returns the right name. Also the add_action('wp_head') works as well. I only can't get the wp_title filter not to work.

Am I executing this filter at the wrong moment or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't tell from the code you have provided, but are you using:

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

in your `<head>`, under header.php?

**UPDATE**

Apparently a change was made to the way titles are handled as of 4.4.  Here is a link that explains how to use the new code:

https://www.developersq.com/change-page-post-title-wordpress-4-4/

```
/*
 * Override default post/page title - example
 * @param array $title {
 *     The document title parts.
 *
 *     @type string $title   Title of the viewed page.
 *     @type string $page    Optional. Page number if paginated.
 *     @type string $tagline Optional. Site description when on home page.
 *     @type string $site    Optional. Site title when not on home page.
 * }
 *     @since WordPress 4.4
 *     @website: www.developersq.com
 *     @author: Aakash Dodiya
*/
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'dq_override_post_title', 10);
function dq_override_post_title($title){
   // change title for singular blog post
    if( is_singular( 'post' ) ){ 
        // change title parts here
        $title['title'] = 'EXAMPLE'; 
    $title['page'] = '2'; // optional
    $title['tagline'] = 'Home Of Genesis Themes'; // optional
        $title['site'] = 'DevelopersQ'; //optional
    }

    return $title; 
}
```

Comment: I think so. Thats what in the standard wordpress theme right? Its in a plugin so every kind of title should be replaced

Comment: It appears to be in twentyfourteen, but I don't see it in twentyfifteen or twentysixteen.  I never use default WP themes, so I'm not sure... but I have used similar code to what you have dozens of times.  I always make sure the wp_title() is called manually...  Add it in and see if things change.

Comment: It should work from within the plugin because its going to be used on many sites. So I don't want to change anything to the theme

Comment: Which default WordPress theme are you using?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect new WordPress title method.

Comment: Nice, thank you!! So frustrating that the WP codex doesn't officially reference this in lieu of the fact that wp_title is being deprecated.

Comment: For anyone else getting here after trying to change this, note that the tagline (site description) is _not_ put in the title by default. I got it in easily by using this answer and setting `$title['tagline'] = get_bloginfo('description');`.

Answer (score 34):

If anyone else is having problems with this, it may be due to the Yoast plugin. Use:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function( $title ){
    // Make any changes here
    return $title;
}, 999, 1 );
```

Comment: To get around Yoast's title filters but keep the benefits of `document_title_parts`,  we can also return an empty string in the `wpseo_title` filter: `add_filter('wpseo_title', '__return_empty_string');` That seems to get Yoast to fallback to the native WordPress title.

Answer (score 4):

I posted this answer to another question but since it is relevant and more up-to-date, I though it might be useful.

How document title is generated has changed since Wordpress v4.4.0. Now `wp_get_document_title` dictates how title is generated:

```php
/**
 * Displays title tag with content.
 *
 * @ignore
 * @since 4.1.0
 * @since 4.4.0 Improved title output replaced `wp_title()`.
 * @access private
 */
function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
}
```

Here is the code from v5.4.2. Here are the filters you can use to manipulate title tag:

```php
function wp_get_document_title() {
    /**
    * Filters the document title before it is generated.
    *
    * Passing a non-empty value will short-circuit wp_get_document_title(),
    * returning that value instead.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param string $title The document title. Default empty string.
    */
    $title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
        return $title;
    }
    // --- snipped ---
    /**
    * Filters the separator for the document title.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param string $sep Document title separator. Default '-'.
    */
    $sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', '-' );

    /**
    * Filters the parts of the document title.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param array $title {
    *     The document title parts.
    *
    *     @type string $title   Title of the viewed page.
    *     @type string $page    Optional. Page number if paginated.
    *     @type string $tagline Optional. Site description when on home page.
    *     @type string $site    Optional. Site title when not on home page.
    * }
    */
    $title = apply_filters( 'document_title_parts', $title );
    // --- snipped ---
    return $title;
}
```

So here are two ways you can do it.

First one uses `pre_get_document_title` filter which short-circuits the title generation and hence more performant if you are not going make changes on current title:

```php
function custom_document_title( $title ) {
    return 'Here is the new title';
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'custom_document_title', 10 );
```

Second way uses `document_title_separator` and `document_title_parts` hooks for the title and the title seperator that are executed later in the function, after title is generated using functions like `single_term_title` or `post_type_archive_title` depending on the page and about to be outputted:

```php
// Custom function should return a string
function custom_seperator( $sep ) {
   return '>';
}
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'custom_seperator', 10 );

// Custom function should return an array
function custom_html_title( $title ) {
   return array(
     'title' => 'Custom Title',
     'site'  => 'Custom Site'
    );
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_html_title', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have trawled through each and every solution on the web trying 100s of examples.

In the end... Well Done **joemaller** As putting this first solved everything!

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', '__return_empty_string');
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simple answer is using this variable.**

```
document_title_parts();
```

**For example:**

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title ){
  // Customize here
  return clean( $title );
}, 10 );
```

**Output before:**

```
#Page Title
```

**After Output:**

```
Page Title
```

Thanks.